# Swiftmailler send the same email twice

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I have a problem when i want send a email after a registration, i realy send a email but i send it twice and dont know why,
this is my code, i created a service who send mail.

my mailerHandler :

```
> public function emailUserPassword(UserInterface $user) {
>     $message = (new \Swift_Message('********'))
>         ->setContentType('text/html')
>         ->setFrom('********')
>         ->setTo($user->getEmail())
>         ->setBody($this->twig->render('Mail/password.html.twig', array(
>             'user' => $user,
>         )));
>     $this->swiftmailler->send($message); }
```

my controller :

```
if (isset($lastName, $firstName, $email, $roles, $stations)) {
            $user = new User();
            try {
                $user->setFirstName($firstName);
                $user->setLastName($lastName);
                $user->setEmail($email);
                $user->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $passWordGenerator));
                $user->setRoles($roles);
                $user->setStations($stations->getValues());

                $entityManager->persist($user);
                $entityManager->flush();

                $event = new UserEvent($user);
                $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(SecurityEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

            } catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
                $dataError = [
                    'status' => 'errorException',
                    'message' => 'existe'
                ];
                return new JsonResponse($dataError, 500
                );
            }

            $dataValid = [
                'type' => 'Validation',
                'valid' => 'L\'utilisateur ' . $user->getFullName() . ' a été créé.'
            ];

            return new JsonResponse($dataValid, 201);
```

and my event:

```
public function __construct(MailerHandler $mailerHandler
) {
    $this->mailerHandler = $mailerHandler;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [SecurityEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess'];
}

/**
 * @param UserEvent $event
 */
public function onRegistrationSuccess(UserEvent $event) {
    $user = $event->getUser();
    $this->mailerHandler->emailUserPassword($user);
}
```

I cant see why i send 2 emails

Comment: have you tried dumping a stack trace in your event handler to see where they're coming from?

Comment: Do you have a service configuration for your EventSubscriber? Sometimes it can happen that a listener/subscriber is registered twice by accident. Maybe you can check your EventDispatcher for which listeners are registered, e.g. using the debug command: `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher <event-name>` or the web profiler toolbar

Comment: i did your command and i have twice "App\EventListener\PassWordListener::onRegistrationSuccess()  " with 0 priority

Comment: I think services that implement the `EventSubscriberInterface` are registered automatically and you don't have to register them "again" in services.yaml

Comment: ohhh thank you yes i had declared my service in service.yaml and when i remove it i send 1 mail now, on symfony 3 I did not have this problem, so yeah its work now thank you two